# Grails drop down with a composite id

Tags: grails, composite-key

I need to populate a drop down list for a search function.  I am having some difficulties because the table has a composite id.  I believe that I will have to reference both foreign keys but not sure how.

Oracle 11g local and READ ONLY
gGrails 2.3.3

Here is my domain with the composite key

```
static belongsTo = [trustee:Trustee, committees:Committees]//

    static constraints = {          
        position nullable:true
        type nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'BOT_TRUSTEE_COMMITTEES'
        version false
        id composite: ['trustee','committees'] 
        trustee column:'TRUSTEE_ID'
        committees column: 'COMMITTEE_ID'

        position column:'POSITION'
        type column:'TYPE'          
    }
```

Here is the view template calling my drop down list

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="hospital">
            <g:message code="hospitals.hospitalName.label" default="Hospital:" />       
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <g:select name="hospitalId" from="${Hospitals.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" optionValue="hospitalName" noSelection="['null':'-Choose a hospital-']"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- Committee drop down list -->
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="committee">
            <g:message code="committees.description.label" default="Committee:" />      
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <g:select name="committeesId" from="${Committees.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" optionValue="committeeName" noSelection="['null':'-Choose a committee-']" />
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- Type drop down list -->
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="type">
            <g:message code="membership.type.label" default="Type:" />      
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <!-- input drop down list for type here -->
        <g:select name="trusteeType" from="${TrusteeMembership.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" optionValue="type" noSelection="['null':'-Please select one-']"/>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In your last you have optionValue="type" .. Is that correct ? try renaming it to trustName or something else just incase your hitting some reserved words in something somewhere...

Comment: type is correct.  I understand that it could be a reserved word.  The issue is with the optionKey.  Do to the fact that this table is using a composite key instead of a primary key.  I put in one of the foreign keys and that populated the list yet there are several duplicates.  How would I just display the distinct values?

Comment: yep indeed since it seems you have no id and your looking for it..http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys.. Look for: To retrieve an instance by id you use a prototype of the object itself: 
. Also take a look here, https://sergiosmind.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/mapping-composite-primary-key-in-grails/. so maybe you need to provide your own hashMap list to from a controller above and set your custom <g:select from="${customReturn}" optionKey="key" optionValue="value" and that will then parse your map to key values and show it.